# Should I build new interior wall over ceramic tile flooring?

Tags: bathroom, walls

I'm making a new bathroom out of an empty space. So I'm erecting interior walls, by laying bricks. The apartment is all concrete. Does one need to cut the tiles or just lay it over them? And if so how do I make sure I'm doing it right?

Comment: Apartment? Is this a rental unit? If so are you landlord or tenant?

Comment: I own it, it's old apartment but building new rooms.